# There's an error in the process of receiving numbers

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
num = n
cnt = 0

while True:
    a = num // 10
    b = num % 10
    c = (a + b) % 10
    num = (b * 10) + c
     
    cnt += 1
    if num == n:
        print(cnt)
        
        break
```

---

```
C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/ADMIN/loc-git/Study_CodingTest/baekjoon/Bronze/1110번.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ADMIN\loc-git\Study_CodingTest\baekjoon\Bronze\1110번.py", line 2, in <module>
    n = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '& C:/Users/ADMIN/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/ADMIN/loc-git/Study_CodingTest/baekjoon/Bronze/1110번.py'
```

---

python version = 3.10.0

Comment: what is your input in your code

Comment: what do  you need plz say more.....

Comment: The reason for the failure is the input you give to the script. Make sure the input you provide is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Dont't understand what you need. but chack this code don't come any error:-

```
n = int(input("enter number"))
num = n
cnt = 0

while True:
    a = num // 10
    b = num % 10
    c = (a + b) % 10
    num = (b * 10) + c
     
    cnt += 1
    if num == n:
        print(cnt)
        
        break
```

Comment: Oh, it was a mistake.